# cannot install ezproxy on ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel, rhel6

not able to install ezproxy on ec2 instance  there seems to be problem because it has a public and private ip.
i used this method for installation from url
https://www.oclc.org/support/services/ezproxy/documentation/download/install-linux.en.html
it fails at step 4 and step 5
error

```
Checking ability to directly connect to iptest.ezproxy.com
Attempting to contact iptest.ezproxy.com by name
Connection established, sending my IP address (10.135.235.34) for testing
Waiting for response on port 0
The test results follow:

If you are using multiple IP interfaces on your system, some of
the information provided by this test may be inaccurate.

You claim to be ip-10-135-235-34.ec2.internal at address 10.135.235.34
To me, you appear to be 54.242.97.3
Since those don't match, there may be a proxy server between us.

I am now attempting to connect to your server to check for intervening
firewalls.  If there is a firewall, this may take a little while.

Trying ip-10-135-235-34.ec2.internal
Connection to ip-10-135-235-34.ec2.internal failed, trying 10.135.235.34
Connection to 10.135.235.34 failed, trying 54.242.97.3
Connection to 54.242.97.3 failed

I am unable to connect to you.  There may be a firewall between us.

Your system claims that its host name is ip-10-135-235-34.ec2.internal
That name failed to work, which may indicate a problem or may
have occurred if you have multiple IP addresses on this server.
```

Comment: What command did you use or what steps did you follow for installing ezproxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 54.242.97.3 your public ip address?  If so, EZProxy should have been able to connect.  Double check your EC2 security group to ensure it allows traffic on the ports that EZProxy requires.

If 54.242.97.3 is not your public ip address, you are probably connecting through a NAT gateway.  Follow the instructions for setting up EZProxy behind a NAT gateway.